# MySql fulltext search amongs results

Tags: mysql, full-text-search

I am must make a search amongs results from other search. So I think in a stored procedure which store in temp_table the results. then search the new term in this temp_table (creating other temp_table). And Again the same story if exist a new search amongs the new results.

Is posibble to create full text indexes in temp_table?
Could Exist low bass performance?

Any recommendation

Thanks in advance. Sorry for my english.

Comment: Have a look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281852/pass-index-to-temporary-table-from-regular-table

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used dynamic nested select queries.

When I can I will post a example code for this problem. Excuse me.

Thank you very much for their help.