# MYSQL: Save Query Results For Subsequent Joins

Tags: mysql, join

I am developing an application for my college where users will be able to define a filter and view posts of students that match the filter criterion.

Initially, MYSQL will query to find the `user_id` of all students that match the filter parameter (year, major, etc). It will then use this result to query and find the corresponding posts/events linked to those `user_id`'s via JOIN.

QUESTION:

Since the same `user_id`'s are used for several times for separate JOIN queries (events, posts, etc.), I was wondering if it would be possible to internally store the results in mysql to speed up subsequent JOIN queries that use the data.

REJECTED SOLUTIONS:

1. Use MySQL query cache - does not apply as the queries are not the same each time; the initial join sequence is the same but then a different join parameter is applied to each query.
2. Pull data into API (php) and then send query using a long `where user_id = IN(#, #, #...)`. There may be 10,000 user ids to send back to MYSQL. The query would be so large it would offset the JOIN savings.

Comment: [`CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/create-table.html) is commonly used for that.

Comment: Temporary tables can also be indexed for maximum `select` performance, see for example [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3281852/pass-index-to-temporary-table-from-regular-table).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't solve performance problems that don't exist.  That is, first try out the various queries.  If they meet the performance criteria for the application, continue and do other things.  Users are more interested in more features and more stability, than in squeezing microseconds out of inner loops.

That said, the normal process is a temporary table.  However, if your joins are properly indexed and the result sets are small (that is, you are not doing full table scans), then the performance gain may be negligible.

Comment: I wholeheartedly agree with you regarding performance. However, the resultset will be utilized for 5 subsequent queries. I would like to profile and benchmark to see if the temporary table is worthwhile my efforts. Thank you.

Comment: I have nothing whatsoever against performance and designing for performance.  Do benchmark the queries.  When benchmarking, remmember to run the queries multiple times.  A first run is often slower than subsequent runs due to cache performance (which is also why the subsequent queries will run faster than the first one).

Answer (score 0):

`create or replace view database.foo_query_view as select id from students where [match-criteria]`. Do note that [views are read-only](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/create-view.html). However, given that you seem to be wanting to do only selects, it should be fine.

Comment: Views apply only for that specify query; I require the result set to be saved for subsequent queries (entire mysql session). Temporary tables seem like the way to go